# inversion on $\mathbb{R}^n/\{0\}$ is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Question is to prove that :

Inversion on $\mathbb{R}^n/\{0\}$ is homeomorphism.

By inversion i mean for a fixed real number $R>0$ the function

$f : \mathbb{R}^n/\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n/\{0\}$ where $x \rightarrow \frac{Rx}{|x|^2}$ i.e., $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\rightarrow \big(\frac{Rx_1}{|x|^2},\frac{Rx_2}{|x|^2},\dots, \frac{Rx_n}{|x|^2}\big)$

I need to prove this $f$ is a homeomorphism.

what i have done so far is to prove this is bijection (invertible)

consider $f\circ f (x)=f(f(x))=f(\frac{Rx}{|x|^2})=\frac{R.\big(\frac{Rx}{|x|^2}\big)}{\big(\frac{Rx}{|x|^2}\big)^2}=\frac{R^2x}{|x|^2}.\frac{|x|^4}{R^2|x|^2}=x$

i.e., we have $f\circ f(x)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n/\{0\}$.

So, $f$ is invertible and $f^{-1}=f$ So, This would help me to reduce my work.

It would be enough to see just $f$ is continuous.

we consider $f_i: \mathbb{R}^n/\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $x_i\rightarrow \frac{Rx_i}{|x|^2}$

I see map $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\rightarrow Rx_i$ is continuous as it is just projection (and multiplying by a constant)

and $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\rightarrow \frac{1}{|x|^2}$ is continuous (not very sure about the proof) I see this is well defined as $x\neq 0$ so, $|x|^2\neq 0$ and thus well defined.

I have $x\rightarrow g(x)$ is continuous and  $x\rightarrow h(x)$ is continuous thus  $x\rightarrow \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ is continuous.

Thus, $$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\rightarrow \big(\frac{Rx_1}{|x|^2},\frac{Rx_2}{|x|^2},\dots, \frac{Rx_n}{|x|^2}\big)$$

is continuous.

It would be helpful if someone can help me to identify any gaps in the proof and help me to rectify this.

Thank you

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @copper.hat:  Thank You

Comment: I would mention that if $f,g:R^n \rightarrow R$ continuous then $h = (f,g) = f\times g$ continuous.